# Open ball definition: $\|x-y\|<r$ for $x=0$?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

What is the open ball definition: $$B(x,r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R^n}: \|x-y\|<r\}$$ for $x=0$?

That is, what is
$$\|0-y\|=\|-y\|<r$$

Comment: I was confused because the norm is defined to be positive. But it didn't mean that the vector had to be positive.

Comment: The vector doesn't need to be positive. It's just that the norm of $y$ is equal to the norm of $-y$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\|-y\|={\lvert-1\rvert}\cdot{\|y\|}=\|y\|$. So $B(0,r)$ is $\{y\in\Bbb R^n:\|y\|<r\}$, or the set of all points whose distance from the origin is less than $r$.

This is **a ball centered on the origin with radius $r$, not including its boundary.**

Answer (score 0):

$||-y||$ is just $||y||$ so $B(0,r)$ only means that those $y\in \Bbb R^n$ with norm less than $r$.

It follows from the property of norm that 
$$
||ax||=|a|\cdot ||x||
$$

Answer (score 0):

Um.  It's be $B(0,r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R^n}: \|0-y\|<r\}$.

Or in other words $B(0,r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R^n}: \|y\|<r\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a ball centered at zero, that is at the coordinate system's origin.